# ASP.NET WebForms 4.0 Site with IE11 does not load ScriptResource for PageRequestManager on Windows Server 2003

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms, windows-server-2003, internet-explorer-11

I am having a problem with IE11 and ASP.NET Web Forms (.NET 4.0) that runs on Windows Server 2003. On IE11, the following script tag does not appear in the source HTML:

```
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=WYhXIHdkh3HFOMewc5Dscl74H0FlrdD4oOAIu08capt3uxzykhWmBntlCyp0ApmvoCoZjoSCP5s1mUjzhOe99tXFvkHJ2vmkIMEuekr4y9dZdi8--YB4rXK6XO-b-mgnKReGNiAy9wDYm6lNNWWtBg2&amp;t=ffffffffbd2983fc" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And subsequently IE11 reports:

```
Unable to get property 'PageRequestManager' of undefined or null reference
```

It works fine in all other browsers.

I guess it has something to do with Browser Definitions. Any one knows how to fix this problem?

UPDATE:

The web site works on my local computer with Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2013 and .NET 4.5.1.

You cannot install .NET 4.5 or 4.5.1 on Windows Server 2003, and therefore we cannot update the server with these packages, but we have to do with .NET 4.0.

Also, it seems that the server recognizes the browser as low-level browser, because session cookie support on "Auto" sets the mode to "cookieless", so that cookie is written as a part of the URL.

Hope this information helps us to solve the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: See issue 2 at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2836939 which describes your problem. You may have to apply the server patches described in that issue.

Comment: Hello Paul. We tried to install the KB2836939 on our server (Windows Server 2003), but it did not solve the problem. However, the site works fine on my local computer with VS 2013 installed. So, it must be something related to the server.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We found finally the answer from the following question:

['WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions' is undefined in IE11 Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244223/webform-dopostbackwithoptions-is-undefined-in-ie11-preview)

We had CSSFriendlyAdapters.browser file in App_Browsers, which caused the problem.

We had to

1) create ie11.browser file as follows:

```
<browsers>
  <browser id="IE11" parentID="Mozilla">
    <identification>
      <userAgent match="Trident\/7.0; rv:(?'version'(?'major'\d+)(\.(?'minor'\d+)?)(?'letters'\w*))(?'extra'[^)]*)" />
      <userAgent nonMatch="IEMobile" />
    </identification>
    <capture>
      <userAgent match="Trident/(?'layoutVersion'\d+)" />
    </capture>
    <capabilities>
      <capability name="browser"              value="IE" />
      <capability name="layoutEngine"         value="Trident" />
      <capability name="layoutEngineVersion"  value="${layoutVersion}" />
      <capability name="extra"                value="${extra}" />
      <capability name="isColor"              value="true" />
      <capability name="letters"              value="${letters}" />
      <capability name="majorversion"         value="${major}" />
      <capability name="minorversion"         value="${minor}" />
      <capability name="screenBitDepth"       value="8" />
      <capability name="type"                 value="IE${major}" />
      <capability name="version"              value="${version}" />
    </capabilities>
  </browser>

  <!-- Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11,0) like Gecko -->
  <browser id="IE110" parentID="IE11">
    <identification>
      <capability name="majorversion" match="11" />
    </identification>

    <capabilities>
      <capability name="ecmascriptversion"    value="3.0" />
      <capability name="jscriptversion"       value="5.6" />
      <capability name="javascript"           value="true" />
      <capability name="javascriptversion"    value="1.5" />
      <capability name="msdomversion"         value="${majorversion}.${minorversion}" />
      <capability name="w3cdomversion"        value="1.0" />
      <capability name="ExchangeOmaSupported" value="true" />
      <capability name="activexcontrols"      value="true" />
      <capability name="backgroundsounds"     value="true" />
      <capability name="cookies"              value="true" />
      <capability name="frames"               value="true" />
      <capability name="javaapplets"          value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsCallback"     value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsFileUpload"   value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsMultilineTextBoxDisplay" value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsVCard"        value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsXmlHttp"      value="true" />
      <capability name="tables"               value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsAccessKeyAttribute"    value="true" />
      <capability name="tagwriter"            value="System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter" />
      <capability name="vbscript"             value="true" />
    </capabilities>
  </browser>
</browsers>
```

2) And then delete __browserCapabilitiesCompiler.compiled from the bin directory.

Now everything is working fine!

I hope this helps also others who are having the same problem!

Comment: I placed the IE11.browser in App_Browsers and deleted the __browserCapabilitiesCompiler.compiled from temporary ASP.NET files under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v.40.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\... and then I recycled the app pool. These steps worked for me!

Comment: I just want to point that this may not work as there may be some stuff between 7.0; (and )?rv: (I had Touch; for example)

Comment: I tried all of the above steps, but it had no effect at all on my Server 2003 ASP.NET web site. Still I get no post back from an ASP.NET drop down list when using IE11 and changing the selected index/item. Everything works perfectly in other browsers like IE10, Safari, Chrome and Firefox.