# x-ua-compatible not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, internet-explorer, meta-tags

I have a website http://resus.softwarewant.com.  It is not working in IE because of the compatibility view.  It work properly only if I add the domain in the compatibility view setting.  I already using the X-UA-Compatibility tag in the very top of head tag but no luck.  Can anyone please help?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: It's not because of the `X-UA-Compatibility` tag. IE picks the right rendering mode, your page does not work because of something else. (No, I can't tell you what it is. But rendering mode is not it.)

Comment: Yes, I got error "Unable to get property 'PageRequestManager' of undefined or null reference".  But once I added the domain in compatibility view setting, no error found.  You can try it.

Comment: I got the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19657220/asp-net-webforms-4-0-site-with-ie11-does-not-load-scriptresource-for-pagerequest/20071590#20071590 Thanks a lot everyone

Comment: I've marked this question as duplicate. Thanks for posting the cross-reference!