# Internet Explorer 11 Session Issue with Asp.Net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, session, iis-7

I am experiencing a strange problem i have developed a website in asp.net 4.0, it works fine on all the browsers as i am handling sessions as well so user has to login to use the site.

On Internet Explorer 11 when you go the the website url it appends strange string in the url.

When you logs in to the website, and click an link inside it logs you out.

I am not sure why this is happening, as i have tested this on locally it works fine, but when the files are uploaded to server and you open the link from IE11 it creates this problem.

Anyone could help me with this, please.

This is the url i get

http://wwww.someurl.com/FM2/(S(iyrnv2rrbds5uisv2qqc3rjy))/login.aspx

Thanks

Comment: This might help http://botsikas.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/ie11-and-aspnet-session-cookies.html

Comment: Thank you very much to you it has fixed this issue. Thanks again ,please post this as answer so i can marked it

Comment: For anyone confronted with this: If you also have a doPostback-Error, you're probably facing another IE11 + .NET4.0 + IIS issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244223/webform-dopostbackwithoptions-is-undefined-in-ie11-preview/21312450

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with the new user agent string (most sites don’t recognize the new IE) and thus MVC doesn’t enable cookies by default

Force the use of cookies in the authentication token by adding the cookieless attribute in your forms authentication element as follows

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/YourLoginUrl" timeout="2880" cookieless="UseCookies" />
</authentication>
```

Source: http://botsikas.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/ie11-and-aspnet-session-cookies.html

Comment: Curse you Browser Capabilities and User Agent sniffing!

Comment: I am glad you posted this answer because it may help some. It did not help me, however. I will post my solution when I find it.

Comment: Hi all, may i know, why facebook login page display as blank n asp.net(4.0) in IE11? thanks.