# IE11-Only Submit Bug

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a form on a page, something simple like:

```
<form action="form/submit" method="post">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

It works in every single browser, including older versions of IE, BUT in IE11 it fails, with the tab stuck in a continuous loading loop, never changing to the "thank you" page after submission. HOWEVER, if I open the console, it DOES work.

I'm aware of the console.log issues IE has, and already am using:

```
if (!window.console) {
    console = {
        log: function() {}
    };
}
```

to avoid it, which seems to be doing fine (as mentioned, every other IE works). Any insight as to where the issue might lie?

Comment: Are you using JavaScript for the `onsubmit` event?  Or is this just a "normal" form?

Comment: Are you sure compatibility mode is `off`? Sometimes when opening the Developer Console IE changes how the page renders and works.

Comment: `console` has more functions than just `log`, depending on your browser. Maybe you're hitting an Error somewhere?

Comment: @RocketHazmat $("form").submit is being used.

Comment: @Nunners I see it running in Edge (document mode), not sure if there's any other compatibility options?

Comment: @Brian: Is that to trigger the submission or to bind to the `onsubmit` event?  Can you show that JavaScript code?  It may be helpful.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen log is the only one used in the JS

Comment: @RocketHazmat Unfortunately I don't think I can share this code, however there are no onsubmit's in the JS, I do see a "try $.post" (with .done/.fail's and a catch) though, does that give enough insight to the submit process?

Comment: @Brian: So... you didn't write this code, then?  Where is the `$.post`?  Is that inside a `$("form").submit(function(){` (or `.on('submit', function(){`)?

Comment: -1 for not posting code that can reproduce the issue. Even if you can't post your code you should be able to post a link to a fiddle that can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 32):

The problem appears when a form only has input elements without a `name` attribute (or no input elements). I found a reference to the bug here, though it also happens in desktop mode and not just metro mode as the link claims:

http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/807447/ie-11-metro-version-submitting-form-fails-if-input-tag-has-no-name-attribute

The fix is to create a dummy `<input type="hidden" name="dummy" value="something">` field (with a name and value set) before submitting the form.

The bug happens in all compatibility modes offered by IE11.

Comment: This is happening to me, but this fix did not work.  New bug perhaps?

Answer (score 11):

I just spent WAY too much time on this bug. The crazy part is, IE11 allow the form submission if you have the dev tools (f12) open. This is what I put before my submit button:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ie11sux" id="ie11sux" value="<?php echo md5(microtime()."ie11sux"); ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 10):

It's a bug in IE11. You can fix it if you add a name attribute to the button, like:

```
<button type="submit" name="foo" ...
```

Comment: Right on, but this won't work without a **value** attribute also added.

Answer (score 7):

A form without named element will result in an infinite loop on submit on IE11 + W8.1. To fix that, simply add an attribute **name** to the button:

```
<form action="form/submit" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="cm" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't directly relate to OP's question, but is an IE-only form submission issue:

If you happen to set `form.prop('disabled', true)` during the submit event, other browsers will still send the form data, but IE will not - it'll send an empty request body.

Comment: About to check this - but it sounds like the exact sort of issue I'm currently battling!

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had empty hidden fields that were marked required. Pretty stupid but it was the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For IE11, there is :

```
event.returnValue = false;
```

Checking if event.preventDefault exists prevent an eventual error :

```
event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue = false);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is caused by a issue with .net 4 on server side. 
Please read this: ['WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions' is undefined in IE11 Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244223/webform-dopostbackwithoptions-is-undefined-in-ie11-preview)

You can enable your IE debug function and try submit, you may see the error: WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions

I fixed a similar submit problem for IE11 by patch this:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2836939

Comment: The OP doesn't mention .NET at all.