# 'Page_IsValid' is undefined IE 11

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-11

In IE 11, ASP.Net 4.0 client side validation not working. Same working for other browsers.
'Page_IsValid' is undefined
'Page_ClientValidate' is undefined

When I check the generated page source, the ScriptResource.axd is not registered in IE.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: have you updated your browser file?

Comment: what version of .net?

Comment: I have generated the browser file using nuget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing this on the server did the trick for me http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2836939

I found the info for the fix here ['WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions' is undefined in IE11 Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244223/webform-dopostbackwithoptions-is-undefined-in-ie11-preview/18325386#18325386)