# IE 11 Browser and Major Version change and Meta tags

Tags: html, asp.net, internet-explorer, razor

I'm working on an ASP.NET website. I have a function where I detect the Browser Name and Version to redirect old browsers to an unsupported website.

I'm using the `HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser` to pull out the 'Browser' and 'MajorVersion' from it.

When I run it from Visual Studio and it runs locally, Internet Explorer 11 comes in as

```
Browser: internetexplorer 
MajorVersion: 11
```

But when I publish it out to our server, it comes in as

```
Browser: ie
MajorVersion: 7
```

All of my layout pages used by the individual razor views have the meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

I don't know why it comes in as a different Browser when I publish this to our dev servers and works fine when running it locally.

The other thing, when I F12 in Internet Explorer, the Compatibility Mode is 7. This changes on its own.

Any ideas on how to resolve it.

If it helps, I've added these tags to the web.config files too in the project to include these meta tags.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of the framework are you targeting?  And what version is installed locally vs the server?  It looks like you have an old version on the server that has not been updated to support the new IE11 User agent format.  Also, the meta tag isn't very reliable, you should the x-ua-compatible HTTP header instead

Comment: I haven't actually checked the .Net version on the server but my machine is targeted for .Net 4.5. Do you happen to know the minimum requirements for the IE11 User agent format?

Comment: I believe that you need .NET 4.5 installed to recognize IE11, or you need to have installed the browser files update.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244223/webform-dopostbackwithoptions-is-undefined-in-ie11-preview/18325386#18325386  Are you sure you're targeting 4.5 and not 4.0?