# WebResource.axd missing from .net webforms site when behind Cloudfront

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to get an existing .net webforms site to work behind Cloudfront but all the webforms break.

Looking deeper -- the site displays fine, but webforms break because the `<script src="/WebResource.axd?[...]">` is completely missing.  Not 404 -- missing -- the script tag is completely missing from the html response.

This seems to be that .NET sniffs browser and responds with a custom build of WebResource.axd for that particular browser+page.

If no [browser match is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244223/webform-dopostbackwithoptions-is-undefined-in-ie11-preview).  No WebResource.axd.

Doing `curl http://some-aspnet-webforms-site.example.com/form.aspx` also seems to confirm this.  No WebResource.axd included.

How do I get Cloudfront to spoof the end-user's browser so WebResource.axd gets included?  (Forwarding cookies and querystring doesn't seem to work and forwarding all headers seems to break cloudfront.)

Or at the very least, how do I force .net to always inject/insert WebResource.axd even when sniffing fails?

Answer (score 3):

The solution was to edit the Cloudfront distribution > Behavior > .net webforms behavior -- and forward headers "Whitelist"; enter only User-Agent.  And of course, forward cookies and optionally querystring.

[image]

It seems like WebResource is compiled [purely based on user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19585664/670023).

Specifically forwarding user-agent fixed the issue and webforms are back to working.

Forwarding "All" headers in Cloudfront was breaking something.  I don't know what/where broke by forwarding all headers, but it gave generic AWS "Access Denied" xml error pages.

Comment: Just found this in the docs "CloudFront replaces the value of [the User-Agent] header field with Amazon CloudFront.": http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#request-custom-headers-behavior