# IE11 form submit not called

Tags: jquery, forms, internet-explorer

We've got a form that's been working for the longest, however we've been seeing a particular bug occuring in Internet Explorer 11.

When we first submit the form using a regular submit button, it fires of the POST request, and everything works as should. However, once we return to the form, and the values we've entered before are filled in for us (editing the data), the submit button does not actually send the POST request, it just stays on the same page.

We've found this to only be the case in IE11, in Edge it works fine, and also in Chrome. The only changes with the form elements is the assigning of values and selected options.

We've tried looking if there are events registered that are blocking the form submit, but couldn't find anything that would block it.

Are there any known issues with submitting forms in IE, or can we get a hand on the best way to debug this? Thanks for any assitance. We're running jQuery 1.11.1 (we've tried running 1.12 already, works with our legacy code, but doesn't solve the issue).

Comment: Is it webforms? If so, you may need to [add a browser file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244223/webform-dopostbackwithoptions-is-undefined-in-ie11-preview).

Comment: Did you check dev tools for errors?

Comment: @Stryner No, we're running Apache with PHP, so no ASP.

Comment: @Musa We checked it, no errors occur apart from some html validity warnings.

Comment: Need more information about your form. Are any parts created dynamically? How is the form created and what attributes are used? Can you edit your post and include some code or example code?.